# Flex Datagrid Item Renderer - issue with index

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have the following problem:

My **datagrid** has a **custom item renderer**, showing a **sparkline**. Each row of the **DG** is displaying a **sparkline** based on the values found in the **datprovider (arrayCollection)**. Now I have an **index** (to display a unique number for each value in the sparkline) counting up within the ItemRenderer.

It seems to work, that `every row in the DG has a unique Renderer with a unique index number`. However, when I `reload the data, the index seems not to be unique` anymore, it keeps on counting even though it should be reset to 0.

here is the code

```
[Bindable]
public var microLineChart_renderer : ClassFactory;

public function init(){
  microLineChart_renderer = new ClassFactory( views.microcharts.renderer.MicroLineRenderer2 );
}

public function loadData( event : ResultEvent){
microLineChart_renderer.properties = { currentIndex: 0};

dg_accounts.dataProvider = result[ 0 ] as Array;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you increment currentIndex?

Comment: can you add your renderer code? You sound like you are running into recyling issues

Comment: thanks for the help - decided to not use the index and generate it in the backend, which seems more stable!